# Dimension error in pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, dimensions

This is my code. It shows a dimension too large error. I have spent a lot of time trying to solve this but have had no success. PLease help me out

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={ln K$_{sp}$ vs 1/Temperature},
        xlabel={1/Temperature (10$^{-3}$K)},
        ylabel={ln K$_{sp}$ (10 $^{-5}$ mol/L)},
        xmin=3, xmax=3.6,
        ymin=-24, ymax=-19,
        xtick={3.1,3.15,3.2,3.25,3.3,3.35,3.4,3.45,3.5},
        ytick={-20,-20.5,-21,-21.5,-22,-22.5,-23},
        legend pos=north east,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]   
    \addplot [thick, domain=-23.5:-19.5,samples=100,]{-4.8878*x-5.4578};    
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.3557,-22.9305 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.3,-21.927 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.246,-21.234 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(3.1949,-20.8286 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.1447,-20.7233 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.0959, -20.5410)};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.0487, -20.3178 )};
        
    \end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have even tried reducing the digits after decimal to 2 but still the error is there

My whole code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}


\title{{\huge \textbf{Experiment 3}} \\ DETERMINATION OF SOLUBILITY AND SOLUBILITY PRODUCT OF A SPARINGLY SOLUBLE SALT AT ROOM TEMPERATURE BY CONDUCTOMETRIC METHOD \\ {\Large Chemistry Lab CY19003} }
\author{Shaurya Goyal \\ 20NA10036 \\Section 2}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \newpage
    \section{Introduction}
    Solubility is the property of a solid, liquid or gaseous chemical substance called solute to dissolve in a solid, liquid or gaseous solvent. The solubility of a substance fundamentally depends on the physical and chemical properties of the solute and solvent as well as on temperature, pressure and presence of other chemicals (including changes to the $pH$) of the solution. The extent of the solubility of a substance in a specific solvent is measured as the saturation concentration, where adding more solute does not increase the concentration of the solution and begins to precipitate the excess amount of solute.\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    
The solubility product constant is the equilibrium constant for the dissolution of a solid substance into an aqueous solution. It is denoted by the symbol $K_{sp}$.

    \section{Formula}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item  The  specific  conductance ($\textbf{k}$) of  the  constituent  ions  of  the  sparingly  soluble salt may be calculated as :
        \begin{center}
            $\textbf{k}_{\text{saturated solution}} - \textbf{k}_{\text{water}} = \textbf{k}_{\text{ion}}$\\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \end{center}

        \item The molar conductance $\lambda$ is: \begin{center}
            $\lambda = \frac{\textbf{k}_{\text{ion}}}{\text{c}}$ \\
            
            \vspace{0.2cm}

            where $c$ is the concentration of the electrolyte in $mol/L$ \\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
        \end{center}
    \item For  a  saturated  solution  of a  sparingly  soluble  salt,   such  as  $BaSO_{4}$:
    \begin{center}
        $c = \left( \frac{1}{\lambda \degree _{\frac{1}{2} \text{Ba}^{2+}} \ + \lambda \degree _{\frac{1}{2} \text{SO} _{4}^{2-}}} \right) \times \textbf{k}_{\text{ion}} = \frac{\textbf{k}_{\text{ion}}}{\lambda \degree _{\text{BaSO}_{4}}} $\\
         \vspace{0.2cm}
         where $\textbf{k} _{\text{ion}}$ is the sum of the ionic conductances of all the ions in the test salt\\ and c is the concentration of the salt in mol/L
    \end{center}
\newpage
\item For the sparingly soluble salt $A_{x}B_{y}$ in  aqueous  solution,  the  solubilization  at  fixed  temperature  and  pressure  can  be  written  as  an  equilibrium  reaction  where  equilibrium  exists  between the solid (undissolved salt) and the ions solution: 
\begin{center}
    \ce{A_{x}B_{y} (s) <=> xA^{y+}(aq) + yB^{x-}(aq)} \\
    the equilibrium constant is given by $K_{\text{sp}} = [A^{y+}]^{x} [B^{x-}]^{y}$
    
\end{center}
\item The heat of solution is:
\begin{center}
    $ln \ K_{s} = - \frac{\Delta H \degree _{sol}}{R} \left( \frac{1}{T} \right) + \frac{\Delta S \degree _{sol}}{R}$
\end{center}
\end{enumerate}
        \section{Graph 1}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                title={Solubility of salt vs Temperature},
                xlabel={Temperature \textcelsius},
                ylabel={c (solubility) (10 $^{-5}$ mol/L)},
                xmin=15, xmax=60,
                ymin=0, ymax=5,
                xtick={20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60},
                ytick={1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4},
                legend pos=north east,
                xmajorgrids=true,
                ymajorgrids=true,
                grid style=dashed,
                ]

                
                \addplot [thick,
                domain=22:57,samples=100,]{0.1055*x-1.5875};    
                    

\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 25,1.05 )};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 30,1.73 )};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 35,2.45 )};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 40,3 )};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 45,3.16 )};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 50, 3.46)};
\addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 55, 3.87 )};

        \end{axis}
      
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \vspace{0.2cm}
   \begin{center}
     The room temperature is 25 \textcelsius.\\
      \vspace{0.2cm}
      The solubility at room temperature is $1.05 \times 10^{-5}$ mol/L \\ The $K_{sp}$ is $  1.1 \times 10^{-10}$
     
   \end{center}
\newpage
\section{Graph 2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={ln K$_{sp}$ vs 1/Temperature},
        xlabel={1/Temperature (10$^{-3}$K)},
        ylabel={ln K$_{sp}$ (10 $^{-5}$ mol/L)},
        xmin=3, xmax=3.5,
        ymin=-24, ymax=-19,
        xtick={3.1,3.15,3.2,3.25,3.3,3.35,3.4},
        ytick={-23,-22.5,-22,-21.5,-21,-20.5,-20},
        legend pos=north east,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        ]   
    \addplot [thick, domain=-23.5:-19.5,samples=100,]{-4.8878*x-5.4578};    
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.35,-22.93 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.30,-21.92 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.24,-21.23 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {(3.19,-20.82 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.14,-20.72 )};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.09, -20.54)};
        \addplot[mark=*] coordinates {( 3.04, -20.31 )};
\end{axis}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\begin{center}
    The slope is -4.8878 (mathematically).\\
    \vspace{0.2cm}
    $- \frac{\Delta H \degree}{R} = -4887.8$\\
    $\therefore \Delta H \degree = 4887.8 \times 8.314$\\
    $\therefore \Delta H \degree =40.64$ kJ/mol
    
\end{center}
    \newpage
```

Comment: If one wraps your fragment into `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, then there is no such error. Conclusion: it comes from something you do not show.

Comment: With `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{pgfplots}`, your code compile fine here with both `pdflatex` and `lualatex`.

Comment: @user240002 the error is at line \end{axis}

Comment: @NBur the error is at line \end{axis}

Comment: Did you try to compile the very minimal code as we did?

Comment: @NBur I did and turns out the error is in the \pgdplotset as 15cm is too big and needs to be 12 cm. Any way around this ? like i have 2 graphs so can i individually set the plot width for both of them ?

Comment: It isn't really the width, the set of keys `xmin=3, xmax=3.5,
         ymin=-24, ymax=-19,` does not make too much sense given where the plot points really are. If you remove them, the error disappears.

Comment: @user240002 thanks so much it works now

Comment: Well done @user240002! I didn't see that, so I added a `restrict y to domain=-30:-15`.

Comment: @ShauryaGoyal you should change the domain for the regression to [0, 5], no? BTW, you should use the `siunitx` package to format your number and units

Comment: @NBur ya i noticed and changed the domain in my tex file. I am a beginner and i didnt know siunitx Ill check it out. also latex isnt compulsory for my submissions but im using it as i wanted to learn it so thanks